# Create array from keys of an array of hashtables

Tags: powershell

I have an array where each element is a hashtable. Each hashtable has the same keys. Here it is:

```
@(
    @{"MarketShortCode"="abc";"MarketName"="Market1"    },
    @{"MarketShortCode"="def";"MarketName"="Market2"    },
    @{"MarketShortCode"="ghi";"MarketName"="Market3"    },
    @{"MarketShortCode"="jkl";"MarketName"="Market4"    }
)
```

I want a nice elegant way to extract an array containing just the value of the MarketShortCode key. So I want this:

```
@("abc","def","ghi","jkl")
```

This is the best I've come up with:

```
$arr = @()
$hash | %{$arr += $_.MarketShortCode}
$arr
```

But I don't like that cos its three lines of code. Feels like something I should be able to do in one line of code. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$hash | %{$_.MarketShortCode}
```

That is, return the value from the block instead of adding it to an array and then dereferencing the array.

If you're using PowerShell 3+, there's even shorter way:

```
$hash.MarketShortCode
```

PowerShell automatically applies dot `.` to each item in an array when it's used this way, but it wasn't supported until v3.

Comment: easy as that eh!! Thanks @briantist. Apparently I have to wait 9 minutes before I can mark that as an answer.

Comment: (This is fairly subjective but) I really prefer `$hash | %{$_['MarketShortCode']}` over the "property"-type deference (`$_.MarketShortCode`) - the latter is ambiguous, `["key"]` isn't

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I prefer dot notation when the property name is to be hard-coded in the script, and item notation (probably not the correct term) with brackets when the name will be generated or chosen at runtime.